# Cannot run 32-bit apps on 64-bit Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, 64-bit, 32-bit

I have a very minimal install of Ubuntu 8.04 64-bit.

When I try to run some 32-bit programs, such as my `jhead` program, I get the message `No such file or directory`.

I figured it may be a library problem, but when I do:

```
ldd jhead
```

instead of a list of libraries it needs, I just get the message `not a dynamic application`.  Same for another old 32-bit app I use.

So it would appear some very important components for running 32 bit apps are not installed.  But how do I even determine what these are?

Comment: You need to install 32bit userland support.  Namely 32 bit versions of ld.so , you'll need more programming specifics though to keep this question open.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You will need to install the 32bit library package

> ia32-libs                                         - ia32 shared libraries for use on amd64 and ia64 systems

go and execute

```
sudo aptitude install ia32-libs
```

Comment: After using up an immense amount of Google's computrons, I just found the same thing.  And ldd magically works after this command too.

Comment: In the newest Ubuntu, install `lib32z1` (`apt install lib32z1`).

Answer (score 0):

Doing ldd ./ might help to see which library dependancies are succesfully resolved.