# Docker ubuntu 16.04 container 64-bit run 32-bit applications

Tags: ubuntu, docker, x86

Is there a general list of the packages needed for a docker 64-bit ubuntu 16.04 container to run 32-bit applications?

I've seen people mentioning `ia32-libs` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34777195/362754) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/735935/362754). Also some others suggested to add to a docker file these:

```
RUN dpkg --add-architecture i386
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y libc6:i386 libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386 zlib1g:i386
```

Is there a more general rule or list of packages usually needed?

Comment: Why do you need something "more general"? Does this not work for you?

Comment: I found the `ia32-libs` from other posts, and my list through trial and error. Obviously this is a more general question, such a random list does not seem to be a good answer to the solution. My guess, embedded in the distro there should be a general meta package for this purpose, thus I'm asking, whether anybody knows such a list or a meta package. No, if it just works for me, it is not the answer I'm looking for.

Comment: Another note that, I've been facing this problem many times. Each time I searched and found an answer, then the next time it would break again. Search at different time gives me different answers. I've lost which is the right answer, if something does not work, just try the next search. That's why I really ask for the ultimate solution to the problem, if it exists.